# Direct connection between two computers with WiFi, without any router

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I have two ThinkPad laptops that I sometimes need to connect directly (without router) with an Ethernet cable and a fixed IP (`10.0.0.1` and `10.0.0.2`), this works well.

**Question: How to do the same with WiFi and no Ethernet cable, i.e. direct connection between two computers via WiFi without any router?**

I vaguely remember about "Ad-hoc" WiFi connection but I don't remember how to enable this.

Note: the WiFi chip on both computers is "Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205". Here is how *"Intel PROSet/Wireless Tools"* looks like (driver install file: "8aw217ww_s64.exe"):

[image]

Comment: Microsoft removed support for ad-hoc wireless networks from Windows 10. On Windows 7 it should still work out-of-the-box. Without additional software.

Comment: @DanielB But where to configure them to be connected with each other? On Computer B, I don't see "Computer A" "Ad Hoc Wifi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 7, support for wireless ad-hoc networking is built-in. Existing ad-hoc networks will be shown in the network list:

[image: connect to network list]

Additionally, you can set up new wireless ad-hoc networks from Network and Sharing Center. Just select “Set up a connection or network”:

[image: Set Up a Connection or Network dialog]

You may want to set static IP addresses on both PCs first, so they can talk to each other without problems.

---

On later Windows version (8.1, 10), Microsoft has gradually reduced/removed support for wireless ad-hoc networking. Third-party wireless management software could still do it, of course.

On Windows 10, the wireless hotspot functionality previously accessible only with `netsh` is now exposed in the new control panel and could also be used to facility direct PC-to-PC networking.

Comment: Thank you @DanielB for your answer. I will try with this! Sidenote: as I sometimes use a Win10 computer too, which freeware third-party solution would you use? (I know this is out of topic, and more for softwarerecs.SE but it's just a sidenote here, not the primary question)

Comment: I’m not aware of any, except Intel’s stuff you already know. // Windows 10 has GUI support for creating a wireless hotspot instead, which can also facilitate PC-to-PC data transfer.

Comment: "Windows 10 has GUI support for creating a wireless hotspot instead": oh this would solve the problem, then, for the Win10 case. Thanks for pointing this out. PS: maybe you can include this information in your answer, it will be useful for future reference/future readers.